# Favorites Question Are Not Been Added To My List?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I am adding Favorites Question & its not adding in my Favorites list

Using Chromium , i think its latest Version

---

## UPDATED

[i have checked lots of people Favorites & find that they got 15 to 20](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/month/askubuntu/2012-02-01/38776#38776)

[image]

Deleted Some Favorites & Added one & Its Showing

is there any Favorites limits ?

Comment: You should include your browser and version in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you're sorting favorites by **activity** - try sorting by **added**:

[image]

Comment: thats a lot ,,, & Me !!!!